# How to get the all child rows recursively using CodeIgniter and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, hierarchical-data

How to get the all child rows and their child rows using CodeIgniter and MySQL?

Here is the Table structure

```
Id  user_id sponser_id

1   1       0
2   2       1
3   3       1
4   4       1
5   5       2
6   6       2
7   7       2
8   8       3
9   8       3
10  10      4
```

I want to get all the child row which is connected under particular `sponser_id`. I have trid this query but I can't get proper detail.

```
$this->db->select('u_fname,u_lname,sponsor_id');
$this->db->from('user_reg');
$this->db->where('sponsor_id', $user_data['otc_id']);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Here is the graphical representation of what i am doing. I want all children row of A and same as b to O.

[image]

I am calling this function from my controller to get the desired output.

#### Controller Code:

```
public function index()
{
    $all_level_array = array();
    $user_data = $this->common->user_data_db();

    $get_user_level = $this->u_buildup_wallet_model->get_user_buildup_level($user_data['otc_id']);

    if(!empty($get_user_level)){

        foreach ($get_user_level as $userData) {

            $test = $this->u_buildup_wallet_model->get_user_buildup_level($userData['otc_id']);

            print_r($test);
        }   
    }


    print_r($all_level_array);
    exit

    $this->load->view();
}
```

#### Model Code:

```
public function get_user_buildup_level($user_otc)
{


    $this->db->select('u_fname,u_lname,sponsor_id,otc_id');
    $this->db->from('user_reg');
    $this->db->where('sponsor_id', $user_otc);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result;
```

Comment: You need some of recursion here

Comment: can you help me over this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961377/php-recursion-help-needed-to-create-a-tree-structure for a solution.